# Removing option from subsequent dropdown based in selection in another

Tags: excel, vba

I have three drop downs in my VBA form (**cbo_fac1**, **cbo_fac2**, **cbo_fac3**), each extracting data from the same source. But I would like to implement a cascade update on the group of select lists so that when the user picks an option from one it is removed from subsequent select lists.

For example if **cbo_fac1** has the following options:

```
Blu-ray DVD Player
Chalk board
Computer 
Data projector
Data projector trolley
```

and the user selects `Blu-ray DVD Player` from **cbo_fac1** then the next two drop downs (**cbo_fac2** and **cbo_fac3**) should only have the following options available:

```
Chalk board
Computer 
Data projector
Data projector trolley
```

If the user then decides to pick `Data projector trolley` from **cbo_fac2** then the next and final drop (**cbo_fac3**) down should only have the following options for selection:

```
Chalk board
Computer 
Data projector
```

Of course if the user decides to go back and change their options then this should also reflect. How would I go about achieving this. This is the code I have so far:

```
   For Each c_fac In ws_misc.Range("fac")
        With Me.cbo_fac1
        .AddItem c_fac.Value
        .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = c_fac.Offset(0, 1).Value
         End With
        With Me.cbo_fac2
        .AddItem c_fac.Value
        .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = c_fac.Offset(0, 1).Value
        End With
        With Me.cbo_fac3
        .AddItem c_fac.Value
        .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = c_fac.Offset(0, 1).Value
        End With
      Next c_fac
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You haven't said which column the text is in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This took longer than I thought.  I thought it was going to be easier :)

I would use a User Defined Type in VBA for this solution.  Please see this example:

Put this in a Module:

```
Option Explicit

Public Type listOptions
    name As String
    isUsed As Boolean
End Type
```

Add three combo boxes on a userform.  Change the combo boxes to the names: cbo_fac1, cbo_fac2, cbo_fac3.

Then add this code behind the userform:

```
Option Explicit

' options needs to be persisted throughout the life of the program
Dim options() As listOptions

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ' setup options
    Call getOptionsFromWorksheet("Sheet1")

    fillComboBoxWithOptions "cbo_fac1"
    fillComboBoxWithOptions "cbo_fac2"
    fillComboBoxWithOptions "cbo_fac3"
End Sub

Private Sub getOptionsFromWorksheet(ByRef wsName As String)
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(wsName)

    ' assuming data begins at A1
    Dim lastCell As Long
    Dim i As Long

    lastCell = ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

    ReDim options(lastCell - 1)

    For i = 1 To lastCell
        options(i - 1) = createOption(ws.Cells(i, 1).Value)
    Next
End Sub

Private Function createOption(ByRef theName) As listOptions
    Dim opt As listOptions
    opt.name = theName
    opt.isUsed = False
    createOption = opt
End Function


Private Sub cbo_fac1_AfterUpdate()
    Call resetSelectedOptions

    ' reset other combo boxes with options
    fillComboBoxWithOptions "cbo_fac2"
    fillComboBoxWithOptions "cbo_fac3"
End Sub

Private Sub cbo_fac2_AfterUpdate()
    Call resetSelectedOptions

    ' reset other combo boxes with options
    fillComboBoxWithOptions "cbo_fac1"
    fillComboBoxWithOptions "cbo_fac3"
End Sub

Private Sub cbo_fac3_AfterUpdate()
    Call resetSelectedOptions

    ' reset other combo boxes with options
    fillComboBoxWithOptions "cbo_fac1"
    fillComboBoxWithOptions "cbo_fac2"
End Sub

' Resets the combobox control with the available options
Private Sub fillComboBoxWithOptions(ByRef comboBoxName)
    Dim selectedItem As String

    ' get and store the selected item, if any,
    ' so we can re-select it after we clear it out and re-fill it
    If (Me.Controls(comboBoxName).ListIndex <> -1) Then
        selectedItem = Me.Controls(comboBoxName).List(Me.Controls(comboBoxName).ListIndex)
    End If

    Me.Controls(comboBoxName).Clear
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To UBound(options)
        If (options(i).name = selectedItem) Then
            Me.Controls(comboBoxName).AddItem options(i).name
        ElseIf (Not options(i).isUsed) Then
            Me.Controls(comboBoxName).AddItem options(i).name
        End If
    Next

    ' re-select the item
    For i = 0 To Me.Controls(comboBoxName).ListCount - 1
        If (Me.Controls(comboBoxName).List(i) = selectedItem) Then
            Me.Controls(comboBoxName).ListIndex = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub resetSelectedOptions()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To UBound(options)
        options(i).isUsed = False
    Next

    ' Since the list index will not match the index of the options() array
    ' we have to loop through until we find a matching name and set
    ' the isUsed = True
    If (cbo_fac1.ListIndex <> -1) Then
        For i = 0 To UBound(options)
            If (options(i).name = cbo_fac1.List(cbo_fac1.ListIndex)) Then
                options(i).isUsed = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End If

    If (cbo_fac2.ListIndex <> -1) Then
        For i = 0 To UBound(options)
            If (options(i).name = cbo_fac2.List(cbo_fac2.ListIndex)) Then
                options(i).isUsed = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End If


    If (cbo_fac3.ListIndex <> -1) Then
        For i = 0 To UBound(options)
            If (options(i).name = cbo_fac3.List(cbo_fac3.ListIndex)) Then
                options(i).isUsed = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End If

End Sub
```

The idea here is that after each combobox has been selected a value, that it would reset the other comboboxes using the AferUpdate event.  It also takes into account if a combobox already had a value selected.

Hope this helps

EDIT:
I changed the code to accommodate data in a worksheet.  I named the sheet "Sheet1" (change this to whatever you need) and I'm assuming that in that worksheet that the ONLY data in there is the list of items you want to have listed (so, NO headers and NO other data in the worksheet at all).

Comment: Thanks bro. I noticed that you've listed the options rather than pulling them out of the spreadsheet. Sorry, my code snippet does not tell the whole story. I'm currently pulling the values out of a spreadsheet. Would this be a problem? Here is the rest of my code: http://pastebin.com/FMsCSQPh

Comment: No problem.  It's not a huge deal, it's just a little more code to work with.  And I did notice that you were using sheet's values after I posted the answer. I didn't know if you could manipulate the code or not for it :)  I can edit the answer pretty quickly, but basically, in the Userform_Initialize event, you would dynamically create the options based on the data in the worksheet.

Comment: I'm a newbie at VBA and I would appreciate it if you could edit out the code. Its been a steep learning curve so far and I feel as if I have been thrown into the deep end!

Comment: I understand how you feel.  I had a job some years ago where I never even heard of VBA before, but after buying a book and hopping on forums and playing around with it I got pretty good at it after a while.  Also, I edited the answer.

Comment: Thank you once again! The sheet is callded **lookupMisc** and the worksheet has different data (with the fac list starting at row 21-38), hence due to the dynamic nature of the data (new facilities being added/removed and so on) I defined the facilities data list with the name **fac**.

Comment: you're welcome!  do you think you can accommodate it on your own to use the Named Range? (I want to give you at least *some* work to do ;)

Comment: Yeah sure bro. I'm assuming that it will follow this format I've been using here: http://pastebin.com/CczU7J0G. What do you think? Where could I implement it?

Comment: The code that I gave you is meant to serve as the full solution to your question, so you would need the bulk of my code for it to work with what you have. Is the concept clear to you? I can explain further if you need. As for the looping through the named range, you can check out this post: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?600204-RESOLVED-Looping-through-a-named-range&s=a463e0aa8f92d6efc5e3a28ded334f72&p=3708436&viewfull=1#post3708436 hopefully that will help.